# iOS UICollectionView, how to animate datasource change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios6, uicollectionview

I'm working with a UICollection view and would like to animate changes to it's datasource. New datasource shares a lot of items with the old one, and I would like to animate insertion of new items and deletion of items that are no longer in the datasource, while keeping all other cells intact:

Current: [1,2,8,9]
Updated: [1,2,3,9]
Changes: insert 3, delete 8

**Are there examples of swapping datasources for UICollectionView with animation?**

I tried this, which causes the collection view to flash, but no animations are being played:

```
 [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

     [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

 }];
```

This method complains about numbers of items not matching:

```
-(void)setDatasource:(NSMutableArray *)datasource
{

    NSMutableArray* _datasourceBackup = _datasource;


    //find out what is being added and deleted
    NSMutableArray* itemsToDelete = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_datasource];
    DLog(@"delete raw: %lu", (unsigned long)itemsToDelete.count);
    [itemsToDelete removeObjectsInArray:datasource];
    DLog(@"delete filtered: %lu", (unsigned long)itemsToDelete.count);


    NSMutableArray* itemsToAdd = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:datasource];
    DLog(@"add raw: %lu", (unsigned long)itemsToAdd.count);
    [itemsToAdd removeObjectsInArray:_datasource];
    DLog(@"add filtered: %lu", (unsigned long)itemsToAdd.count);


    //1 update datasource
    _datasource = datasource;

    if(_datasourceBackup.count == 0)
    {
        //original load
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }else
    {
        [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

            //convert items to add/delete into index paths and give them to collection view to animate
            NSMutableArray* indexPathsToDelete = [NSMutableArray array];
            for(NSString* identifier in itemsToDelete)
            {
                NSInteger index = [_datasourceBackup indexOfObject:identifier];
                [indexPathsToDelete addObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
            }
            if(indexPathsToDelete.count > 0 )
            {
                [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete];
            }


            NSMutableArray* indexPathsToInsert = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:itemsToAdd.count];
            for(NSString* identifier in itemsToAdd)
            {
                NSInteger index = [_datasource indexOfObject:identifier];
                [indexPathsToInsert addObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
            }

            if(indexPathsToInsert.count > 0 )
            {
                [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert];
            }


        } completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Try TLIndexPathTools (https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools). Instead of swapping DataSources, swap what are called DataModels. This can be backed by an array or by Core Data.